# Can't add external file as sd card in AVD emulator

Tags: sd-card, android-studio

My problem is that when i try to add an external file SD card to a virtual device in AVD the option to do so is greyed out. Nothing I've tried to do to fix this has resulted in anything. No matter if I create a new device, alter an existing one or duplicate an existing device This problem still remains. I've google searched for an answer for this but have found nothing that even relates to my problem, despite this happening every time i try, and every time my friend tries as well. I am using Pixel 2 API 28 and running Android studio 3.3 Below is an image of the issue.[This is an image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szp14.pngdio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do it. go to avd, click create virtual device, select your device of choice and pick clone device, finish, and with the cloned device selected click next, and do all the rest of the stuff to create a virtual device. Once your back to the avd manager you can edit your new virtual device and it should allow you to choose an external sd to use, among other things. [Heres what you need to click to clone device.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dio86.png) It turns out I had seen this solution before, but confused clone device in the select hardware page of the virtual device configuration menu with the duplicate device available in the AVD manager menu. I don't know why you need to do this, but hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.